# Cannot download file from s3 bucket using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I have a file that has a location: `https://lms3.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/answers/5/1_4.pdf`.
I have configured the digital ocean space for s3 driver and I can upload the file as well. But when I try to download this file, it says file not found.

For uploading the file, I wrote this code:

```
  $name = auth()->id().'_'.$cq->id.'.pdf';
  $path = Storage::disk('do')->putFileAs('answers/' . $exam->id,$request->file('answer'), $name, 'public');
```

And the `$path` returns me `answers/5/1_4.pdf` that is saved in the database.

The code I have used for the download:

```
$file = Storage::disk('do')->url($path);
return response()->download($file);
```

The response shows an error and says that `https://lms3.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/answers/5/1_4.pdf` does not exists. This is a publicly accessible file. I can not find out what is wrong with this code.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you have configured the `s3` disk in `config/filesystems.php` you can use the **Storage::disk('s3')->download()** to generate the download response. Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#downloading-files

Comment: I tried that also, but no luck. The configuration is ok I think, as I can upload the file to the bucket.

Comment: When you are uploading the file what do you save in the database - can you pls post the code for when you are saving/uploading a file. And then the code to download the file can be relative to the disk root location

Comment: @Donkarnash I have updated the question with more details

Comment: Try to get the file and see if there's any error: `Storage::disk('do')->get($path);`